# Model 'base-value' from RGB

Tags: python, colors, rgb

I have a raster file which only consists of RGB bands. The raster is representing elevation and colors the cells accordingly, but it does not contain any elevation data. Now, I want to change the colors of it in my own custom scale, and therefore I need the elevation-data.

I have a small portion of the raster expressed in sample points (thus i,j and elevation). I can sample the raster-RGB values onto these points so that the points contain the information of (i,j,elevation,r,g,b,a) in a list.

Now I want to analyse the correlation(?) between the set of RGB and elevation using the sample points. Then afterwards I want to go back to the raster and compute the elevation for any cell. Basically I want to have something like this; a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e = elevation

Is this possible, or is assigning the RGB colourscale just too random? Otherwise, any tips on workflows or proposed correlation formulas to make this work? Preferebly in Python2

Edit:
This is a small snippet of the raster:
[image]

Blue is low elevation and Red is high elevation

Comment: I doubt it is random, but you would be well served knowing what mapping has been applied to the elevation data to generate the rub. E.g., does blue mean low and red high?

Comment: You're trying to reconstruct original data from a color representation, right? But a linear model won't work for most color ramps. I'd try to understand which software was used to create the colors, and which colormap exactly used. Alternatively, start by just plotting known (elevation, r) pairs.

Comment: I updated my question with a sample image. And indeed, blue means low and red is high. A good (maybe too straightforward... sorry) point of plotting the elevation against its values. Will try that and see if theres any correlation. I don't have (and cannot get) any information about the used model..

Comment: Hi tiwo, it's been a while since I worked on it, but am still stuck. My rgb plot is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D6Lb.png. It is based on the depth-scale (-20 > 70). Is there any change you can hint me in the right colormap or other thaughts how to achieve this?